# Alamofire with Swift - "Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (ox10a75ebb0) to 'Photomania.PhotoInfo' (0x107ee7b90)."

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Running OS X El Cap dev beta, iOS 9.0, Xcode 7.0 GM

I am following this Ray Wenderlich tutorial ( http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial ) and am really having some issues with it. Before I even create the request router, my app doesn't work. It builds correctly and then as soon as it starts loading, I get the debugger phrase written in the title. The build error description is "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".

The line that is outlined is :

```
let imageURL = (photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PhotoInfo).url
```

Here is my entire code for the PhotoBrowserCollectionViewController.swift file.

```
//
//  PhotoBrowserCollectionViewController.swift
//  Photomania
//
//  Created by Essan Parto on 2014-08-20.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Essan Parto. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire

class PhotoBrowserCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  var photos = NSMutableOrderedSet()

  let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

  let PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier = "PhotoBrowserCell"
  let PhotoBrowserFooterViewIdentifier = "PhotoBrowserFooterView"

  // MARK: Life-cycle

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupView()

//    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.500px.com/v1/photos").responseJSON() {
//        (_, _, data) in
//        print(data.value)}

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.500px.com/v1/photos", parameters: ["consumer_key": "consumer key"]).responseJSON() {
        (_,_,JSON) in
        print(JSON.value)

        let photoInfos = (JSON.value!.valueForKey("photos") as! [NSDictionary]).filter({
            ($0["nsfw"] as! Bool) == false
        }).map {
            PhotoInfo(id: $0["id"] as! Int, url: $0["image_url"] as! String)
        }

        self.photos.addObject(photoInfos)
        print(self.photos)

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }


  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  // MARK: CollectionView

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photos.count
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell

    let imageURL = (photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PhotoInfo).url

    Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).response() {
        (_,_, data, _) in

        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        cell.imageView.image = image
    }

    return cell
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: PhotoBrowserFooterViewIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) 
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowPhoto", sender: (self.photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item) as! PhotoInfo).id)
  }

  // MARK: Helper

  func setupView() {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let itemWidth = (view.bounds.size.width - 2) / 3
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
    layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: 100.0)

    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

    navigationItem.title = "Featured"

    collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier)
    collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoBrowserCollectionViewLoadingCell.classForCoder(), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: PhotoBrowserFooterViewIdentifier)

    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    collectionView!.addSubview(refreshControl)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowPhoto" {
      (segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoViewerViewController).photoID = sender!.integerValue
      (segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoViewerViewController).hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
  }

  func handleRefresh() {

  }
}

class PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  let imageView = UIImageView()

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)

    imageView.frame = bounds
    addSubview(imageView)
  }
}

class PhotoBrowserCollectionViewLoadingCell: UICollectionReusableView {
  let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.center = self.center
    addSubview(spinner)
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug through the code, where it actually goes wrong? At what line? Probably something isn't linked up correctly.. The cell that you're using, did you set a class in storyboard? Linked Outlets correctly? Oh and ask for a new consumer key, yours is now public..

Comment: How often are the problems actually not in the line indicated by the debugger ? I just took the sample project so all cells, outlets, classes and everything should be good. Still can't locate the problem :S

Comment: It is probably because some things have changed in swift with all the xcode beta's. I even had to re-add an textbox to fix an app from crashing, so it's worth to take a closer look where the 'magic' happens...

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you add the full array `photoInfos` with

```
self.photos.addObject(photoInfos)
```

instead you should do

```
self.photos.addObjectsFromArray(photoInfos)
```

This will add the array elements in `photoInfos` one by one instead of the entire `photoInfos` array to index 1 of `photos`

Answer (score -1):

I also learning this tutorial and have some problems. first, because of the unstable network connection to the 500px.com server, I get nil from the JSON data, so the photos count is 0, so I can't see any cell in the UI; second, my Xcode's version is 7.2 and Swift 2.0, so I find some changes in my environment. If you follow the tutorial completely, you will get some coding exceptions.

```
self.photos.addObject(photoInfos)
```

You should use function `addObjectForArray(ARRAY_NAME)` instead of `addObject()`.

I don't know weather your version of Xcode and Swift is same to me. I feel there are many changes about coding. so in the closure about the function "response", I write like this:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: [CONSUMER_KEY : CONSUMER_KEY_VALUE])
request.responseJSON{ response in let json = response.result.value ... }

var data:NSData!
        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, (photoMuatbleOrderedSet.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! Photo).image_url!)
        request.responseData { (response) -> Void in
           data = response.data!
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            cell.imageView.image = image
        }
        return cell
```

as these changes, when the App is running, I get no exceptions!

Comment: Hey, I am actually done working on this project, so I don't need help on this photo issue anymore! All the same, thanks for stopping by.